# Run Thunderbird 115 and 112 simutaneously?

Tags: email

Is it possible to "test" Thunderbird 115 alongside 112?  I need to keep ver. 112 running to maintain my setup but;  I would like to try version 115 and experiment with the apparent restrictions of its new layout.

Comment: Use "portable" versions. In Linux, you can have both versions as [AppImage](https://github.com/srevinsaju/thunderbird-appimage/releases)s. Notice you need to use *different profiles* for them, so start at least one of them with `-P` flag.

Comment: And Windows also allows for separate profiles... **But** to be sure there is no interaction, I'd one one or both in VM.